# How can I use Python to download a file without browser when its tag does not show an URL?

Tags: python, url, download, python-requests

**1. What I want**

I would like to **use Python to download a file without Selenium webdriver (PhantomJS, Chrome Driver, etc.)**.

**2. Situation**

Using a **regular** browser (*i.e.* not using robots) the file is automatically downloaded by clicking on a certain icon (see this picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Maw28.png)).

If I could use a Selenium Webdriver, since I know it is placed with the `input` tag below, I could simply do a `driver.find_element_by_id('cphCorpo_ctl01_btExportarTxt').click()` and it would download the file.

**3. Problems**

This is the `input` tag that references the file I am talking about.

```
<input id="cphCorpo_ctl01_btExportarTxt" name="ctl00$cphCorpo$ctl01$btExportarTxt" src="inc/img/txt_file.png" style="height:30px;width:30px;" title="Exportar Dados para .TXT" type="image"/>
```

*Problem 1:* As you can see, there is no `href` tag nor visible url available.

*Problem 2:* The reason I cannot use Selenium / Browsers is because while parsing the full url to the desired webpage, there's a long VIEWSTATE argument which creates a "HTTP Error 414: Request URL too long" (see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ9kj.png)) when using *e.g.* `driver.get(url)`.

**4. What I have tried**

I've tried to find out the url of the downloaded file through the Network browser tab. Although it is possible to get the url of the page that shows the download icon, nothing changes in Network tab when clicking of the download button (even though the file is downloaded).

**Possible Solutions**

I can think of three ways that could solve this issue, but couldn't find out how to do them. If one of these can be done, it will solve my problem:

1. Get (somehow) a hidden URL from the  tag
2. "Simulate" a 'click' on the element `soup.find_all('input', attrs = {'id':'cphCorpo_ctl01_btExportarTxt'})[0]` from urllib / Requests / urlopen / etc, just like it can be done when using Browsers / Selenium.
3. Solve the 'URL too long' error in order to use Browsers / Selenium.

**Additional Information**

Since the full URL is too long, I am posting the initial URL:

http://gestorpcd.ana.gov.br/exportarDados.aspx

Which should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4cbr.png)

After clicking in one of the options of the first group (that is the only mandatory group) and selecting dates, the download icon will be available and the webpage should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhZWY.png)

Comment: What is this "URL too long" error you say you're seeing?

Comment: Edited the **Problem 2** subsection with an image of the error. Of course this image was taken using a regular browser but the same happens when using PhantomJs as confirmed by using `driver.save_screenshot`

Comment: Can you provide the steps you took the produce the 414?

Comment: **1.1)** Open Developer Tools in a Browser. **1.2)** Go to Network tab. **2)** Select any *Estado* (1st group), *e.g.* "AC". **3)** Select any "Estacoes" (5th group), *e.g.* "Santa Rosa". **4)** Select date second date (A: dd/mm/yyyy). **5)** Select first date (De: dd/mm/yyyy) earlier than the second date. This order (date to, then date from) is important. **6)** On the network tab, clinck on the last *exportarDados.aspx*. **7)** Concatenate the URL given with a question mark sign '?' and the query parameters. At least in Safari and Chrome this should give a huge `viewstate` argurment.

Comment: Concatenate what query parameters? The form data? That's a POST request. The form data is sent in the body of the request. What makes you think you can simply move that data into the query string and issue a GET request instead? And what makes you think that that's the URL of the download? That request is made before you ever click the icon.

Answer (score 0):

## You can’t download the file without a browser...

... because the file is generated *by* the browser. All of the data is already in memory. When you click the image, some JavaScript code constructs the report, then tricks the browser into saving it to the local file system (likely by telling it to open a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)).

This looks like any other file download, but it’s not. This also explains why you can’t find the URL for the file: there isn’t one.

## You *can* download the file with Selenium...

... so long as you use it in a way that makes sense.

You told Selenium to open a URL that wasn’t valid, which is why you received a 414 status code. That’s not Selenium’s fault: it’s yours. That “URL” wouldn’t have worked with *any* HTTP library—be it curl, wget, requests, or literally anything else.

(As an aside, I don’t understand why you tried to construct a URL for Selenium in that way. I see no reason to believe that that particular POST request represents the current page. What’s more, there’s no reason to assume that you can rewrite an arbitrary POST request as a GET request and have it work.)

If you want to use Selenium, you just need to do what you would manually do with a real browser: visit the report generator, select the desired options, then click the icon:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver.get("http://gestorpcd.ana.gov.br/exportarDados.aspx")

def select_xpath(header):
    return (
        "//select[./preceding-sibling::*[contains(./text(), '{}')]]".format(header))

states = Select(
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(select_xpath("Estados")))
states.select_by_visible_text("AC")

# wait for season options to update

seasons = Select(
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(select_xpath("Estações")))
seasons.select_by_visible_text("MÂNCIO LIMA")

export = driver.find_element_by_xpath("input[@title='Exportar Dados para .TXT']")
export.click()
```